# Stage all but one folder

Tags: git

I have a project containing a few modules. There were some commits previously.

How do I stage all the files (modified, deleted, created) and folders in the project **but** the one specific folder and all files in it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
git add .
git reset -- somefolder_to_exclude
```

Comment: why `add .` and not `add -A .` ?

Comment: Yes, `-A` for all should be fine.

Comment: what's the format for somefolder_to_exclude: somefolder_to_exclude or somefolder_to_exclude/ or somefolder_to_exclude/* ?

Comment: @MariusKavansky you don't need to include the trailing slash or a trailing `/*`.  Just specifying the folder name is enough.  It will unstage the entire subtree.

Comment: On 2019 this works: `git reset HEAD -- somefolder_to_exclude`